# Can't get XML tag value

Tags: java, xmldocument

I have the following code

```
protected static final String TAG_numFound                  = "numFound";        //
Document street_xmlDoc = GetXMLDocument(street_url);
Element results = street_xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();
//numFound
Node numFoundNode = results.getElementsByTagName(TAG_numFound).item(0);
String numFound = numFoundNode.getNodeValue() + "(" + numFoundNode.getNodeName() + ")";
```

and the following XML

```
<results>
<numFound>1</numFound>
<QTime>66</QTime>
<result>
<distance>0.0</distance>
<name>Agua</name>
</result>
</results>
```

And in the numFound String variable I'm getting "null(numFound)"
I don't understand why I'm not getting "1(numFound)" instead.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getTextContent` instead of `getNodeValue`.

Read this [blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) for more info.

You can see when `getNodeValue` has any meaning in this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) section (or in the below snapshot).
[image: node value in XML parsing]

Comment: Thanks, that solve it the problem, now I'm reading the link that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XPath` to get the value, this might be clearer for future readers of your code:

```
    final Document document = //build your document
    final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    final XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile("//numFound/text()");
    final Number output = (Number) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
    System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I had never heard about XPath, it seems easy than use NodeList and Element.